# Apache POI returns null for cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor() when conditional formatting is used

Tags: java, excel, colors, apache-poi

I am trying to read out the color of cells which were set with Excel using conditional formatting. Most of the time this does not work and the color that is returned is null. This applies to both the foreground color as well as the background color. In very few cases the color is read out correctly, but it is still unclear why.

```
XSSFColor color = (XSSFColor)cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor();
```

Here you find the  excel file to reproduce my case: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_oge-F-_yzcswyDtrg5f-T9as733YmMxX0Rs6gmt4Is/edit?usp=sharing

Apache POI version : 4.0.1

**UPDATE:** 
This might be related to Conditional Formatting because when I set the background of a single cell manually it works fine.

Comment: The background color of the cell's `DisplayFormat` differs from the one of the cell style when conditional formatting is used. But to get the `DisplayFormat` needs the following: 1. Check whether the cell is part of a cell range which is conditional formatted (possible). 2. If so, check whether the cell acutally fulfills one of the conditional formatting rules (possible but with very much efford). 3. If so, check whether the rule has pattern formatting (possible). If so, get the background color from that pattern formatting (possible).

Comment: So most elaborate is 2., at least if it is to become a universal solution. And if it not is to becaome a universal solution then checking the cell content and determining the further things from that cell content instead from the color is much more simple. In your case: All cells in `$A$1:$BI$19` containing "RUH" are blue colored. So loop over all cells in `$A$1:$BI$19` and check whether the string cell value is "RUH".

Comment: @AxelRichter ok thanks. So basically the only way is to use the applied conditional formatting